What ring homomorphisms do induce well-defined mapping between principal ideals?
The original question I was going to ask was an attempt to define the notion of a "GCD domain homomorphism", but ultimately it boiled down to another question, so here I go.
Given a ring $R$, let the set of principal ideals of $R$ be denoted by $\langle R \rangle$. Given a ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to S$, a natural question to follow is whether $\phi$ induces a well-defined mapping from $\langle R \rangle$ to $\langle S \rangle$, denoted by $\langle \phi \rangle$. That is, whether the map $\langle \phi \rangle$ defined as $\langle \phi \rangle (\langle x \rangle) = \langle \phi(x) \rangle$ is well-defined.
As long as $R$ is a GCD domain, since $\langle R \rangle$ can be endowed a lattice order structure where $\gcd$ is the join and $\mathrm{lcm}$ is the meet, the notion of a GCD domain homomorphism should follow. But I'm concerned whether the requirement of well-definedness of $\langle \phi \rangle$ is too restrictive.
I tested some ring homomorphisms, such as inclusion map $i : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, the quotient map $q : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, and the evaluation map $\epsilon_0 : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}$. And surprisingly, they are all successful examples. So what is a non-example?

For any ring homomorphism, $\phi\colon R\to S$, you can define a map from the ideals of $R$ to the ideals of $S$ by mapping $I$ to the ideal generated by $\phi(I)$. When $I=(a)$ is principal, the ideal generated by $\phi(I)$ is the ideal generated by $\phi(a)$, so is principal. That is, the map sends principal ideals to principal ideals. And it respects the order; if $a\mid b$, then $\phi(a)\mid\phi(b)$. But an order-preserving map between lattices need not be a lattice morphism.

"And surprisingly, they are all successful examples." Is it really surprising? Considering all rings you've tested are principal ideal domains? :)

@freakish Well, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ isn't...

@ArturoMagidin well, on the right side. The left one isn't relevant if the right one is PID.

A non-example of... what? Are you asking if the map is well-defined from principal ideals to principal ideals, or are you asking if the map will respect gcds?

For more on the divisor (gcd) vs. ideal perspective see the papers by Lucius and Neumann I cite here. They generalize the divisor theory introduced in the classical textbook by Borevich and Shafarevich.

You don't specify if your rings are commutative or have unities, so let me do this as generally as possible for as long as possible...
Let $R$ and $S$ be ring, and let $\phi\colon R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism.
If $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $\phi(I)$ need not be an ideal of $S$, but we can form the ideal of $S$ generated by $\phi(I)$, $(\phi(I))$. In the commutative ring context this is usually called the "extension of the ideal $I$", and for rings with unity it corresponds to $S\phi(I)S$.
This defines a map from the set of ideals of $R$ to the set of ideals of $S$, mapping $I$ to $(\phi(I))$. The map is monotone: if $I\subseteq J$, then $\phi(I)\subseteq \phi(J)$, hence $(\phi(I))\subseteq (\phi(J))$.
In addition, the map sends principal ideals to principal ideals: suppose $I=(a)$. I claim that $(\phi(I))=(\phi(a))$. Indeed: since $\phi(a)\in \phi(I)$, then $(\phi(a))\subseteq(\phi(I))$. Conversely, if $x\in I$, then $x=na+ra+as + \sum_{j=1}^m r_jas_j$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m\geq 0$, $r,s,r_j,s_j\in R$; so $\phi(x) = n\phi(a) + \phi(r)\phi(a)+\phi(a)\phi(s) + \sum_{j=1}^m \phi(r_j)\phi(a)\phi(s_j)\in (\phi(a))$, so $\phi(I)\subseteq (\phi(a))$, and hence $(\phi(I))\subseteq (\phi(a))$.
So we certainly get a map from the set of principal ideals of $R$ to the set of principal ideals of $S$; if we partially order both under inclusion, the map is monotone.
So now we move to the case where $R$ and $S$ are GCD domains, so that they are integral domains in which any two elements have a gcd and an lcm, which make the poset of principal ideals into a lattice. Now we have a map from the lattice of principal ideals of $R$ to the lattice of principal ideals of $S$, and the map is monotone. Is it a lattice homomorphism?
The main difficulty is that in general it is not true that a monotone map between two lattices is a lattice homomorphism. That is because if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are lattices, then $f\colon L_1\to L_2$ is a lattice homomorphism if and only if $f(a\wedge b) = f(a)\wedge f(b)$ and $f(a\vee b) = f(a)\vee f(b)$. This implies that the function is monotone, but the converse is not true; for a counterexample, consider the map between the four element diamond lattice $\{0,a,b,1\}$ and the three-element chain $\{0,1,2\}$ that sends $0$ to $0$, $a$ and $b$ to $1$, and $1$ to $2$. This map is (strictly) monotone: if $x\lt y$ then $f(x)\lt f(y)$. But $f(a\wedge b) = f(0) = 0$, and $f(a)\wedge f(b) = 1\neq 0 = f(a\wedge b)$, and $f(a)\vee f(b) = 1\neq 2 = f(a\vee b)$.
So the question here is: if $a,b\in R$ will $(\phi(\gcd(a,b))) = (\gcd(\phi(a),\phi(b)))$?
Since $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $\phi(\gcd(a,b))$ divides both $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$, so we always have that $(\gcd(\phi(a),\phi(b)))\subseteq (\phi(\gcd(a,b)))$. But the converse inclusion need not hold:
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}[z]$. They are both GCD-domains (in fact, UFDs). Note that $\gcd(x,y)=1$. Now let $\phi\colon R\to S$ be the map that is the identity on the coefficients and sends $x$ and $y$ both to $z$. Then we have that $\gcd(\phi(x),\phi(y)) = \gcd(z,z) = z$, but $\phi(\gcd(x,y))=1$.  So here $(\gcd(\phi(x),\phi(y))=(z)\subsetneq (1) = (\phi(\gcd(x,y)))$.
If $R$ is a Bézout domain, though, then it will work. From the above observations we just need to show that $(\phi(\gcd(a,b)))\subseteq (\gcd(\phi(a),\phi(b))$,, or equivalently, that $\gcd(\phi(a),\phi(b))$ divides $\phi(\gcd(a,b))$.
In this situation, we have $(a,b)=(\gcd(a,b))$, so $\gcd(a,b) = ar+bt$ for some $r,t\in R$. Therefore, $\phi(\gcd(a,b)) = \phi(a)\phi(r)+\phi(b)\phi(t)$ which is clearly a multiple of $\gcd(\phi(a),\phi(b))$. So in this situation, we do have equality and we get a lattice morphism between the principal ideals of $R$ and the principal ideals of $S$.
